# Change default file name when downloading from Media Library

Tags: media-library

I store user uploaded files in Media Library, which can later be downloaded by admins. When saving files, I change the file names to guarantee uniqueness, but later when admins download them I want them to see the original or user friendly file name.

This is the line of code behind the download button:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem));
```

Sitecore uses media item name and the extension stored in `Extension` property to construct the default file name. It does not use the display name, nor the title or any other field.

I know that the file name is reflected in the `content-disposition` header and looks like `attachment;FileName.doc`. I want to know if there is any way I can modify that header in the response of the file download so I can have a chance to include my own logic.

I know, I can create my own custom download handler, but my specific question is regarding intercepting media download requests in Sitecore, which is the preferable method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the my final solution after the leads from other answers here. I use the media:request event along with the lesser known AddOnSendingHeaders method on Request object that basically gives me a final chance to change headers before IIS sends the request to the client.

```
public class ChangeFileName
{
    public void OnMediaRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        SitecoreEventArgs eventArgs = args as SitecoreEventArgs;

        MediaRequest mediaRequest = eventArgs?.Parameters?[0] as MediaRequest;
        if (mediaRequest == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaRequest.MediaUri).MediaData.MediaItem;
        if(mediaItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        HttpRequest request = mediaRequest.InnerRequest;

        request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddOnSendingHeaders(context =>
        {
            if (CheckFileType(mediaItem))
                context.Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = FixFileName(context.Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"]));
        });
    }
}
```

Then of course, I had to add the event handler to the config:

```
<event name="media:request">
    <handler type="MyAssembly.ChangeFileName, MyAssembly" method="OnMediaRequest"/>
</event>
```

Comment: Nice. Much cleaner than the original answer you provided.

Answer (score 4):

It used to be possible to add a processor in the `getMediaStream` pipeline and then set `Content-Disposition=true` header in earlier versions of Sitecore but there have been some changes in the latest versions meaning that technique no longer works as expected.

Instead, you should add a handler to `media:request` event instead and handle setting the correct headers and sending the file response back there.

```
public class DownloadProcessor
{
    public void OnMediaRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (!Sitecore.MainUtil.GetBool(Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.GetQueryString("download"), false))
            return;

        ForceMediaDownload(request);
    }

    private void ForceMediaDownload(MediaRequest request)
    {
        var mediaItem = MediaManager.GetMedia(request.MediaUri).MediaData.MediaItem;

        var response = request.InnerRequest.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = mediaItem.MimeType;
        response.Headers.Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + GetFileName(mediaItem));
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.BufferOutput = true;
        mediaItem.GetMediaStream().CopyTo(response.OutputStream);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }

    private static string GetFileName(MediaItem mi)
    {
        // or whatever logic you need to determine the file name
        return ("{0}.{1}".FormatWith(mi.Name, mi.Extension)).Replace(" ", "-");
    }
}
```

And then patch the handler in.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="media:request">
        <handler type="Sitecore.Custom.Pipelines.DownloadProcessor, Sitecore.Custom" method="OnMediaRequest"/>
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Now to force download of any media item, ensure that the URL includes the parameter `download=1`.

From your code snippet in your question, you can use this:

```
string mediaURL = WebUtil.AddQueryString(MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem), "download", "1");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(mediaURL);
```

I have previously written a blog post on forcing download of media items which contains more details and expanded code sample, including error checking: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/11/16/force-download-of-media-files/

Comment: Thanks, your solution definitely works, but the downside is that it is  bypassing the checks and logic implemented in Sitecore to handle file download. For example, resuming download or multi-thread download using HTTP range headers.

At first, I tried to use your code, but only inject the Content-Disposition header. It did not work since after my handler ran, Sitecore added the header again.

So it made me dive deeper and find the code that actually raises that event, which is in MediaRequestHandler as suggested by @Richard. I ended up inheriting from that class to override the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do that in a pipeline, you should look at the `getMediaStream` pipeline. This processes the media for the Sitecore media handler. You could add a new processor in there to set the `content-disposition` header.

Sitecore currently sets headers in a protected method called `SendMediaHeaders` in the `MediaRequestHandler`. This method:

```
/// <summary>Sets the headers.</summary>
/// <param name="stream">The stream.</param>
/// <param name="context">The context.</param>
protected virtual void SendStreamHeaders(MediaStream stream, HttpContext context)
{
  stream.Headers.CopyTo(context.Response);
}
```

copies the headers from the `MediaStream` to the response. So in your processor, you should be able to add a header to the `GetMediaStreamPipelineArgs.OutputStream` and they will be added to your response.

Bare in mind tho, this will not just affect download links, but also anywhere that a media item is downloaded to the browser (images etc...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however that pipeline does not appear to be executed when downloading a non-image file, a PDF file in my test. Looking at the MediaRequestHandler, I cannot ascertain if that handler is being triggered at all.

Comment: The media URL is: 
 /-/media/files/filename.pdf

Comment: Another thing that I found is that for the non-image files that I was using, the SendMediaHeaders method did not add any headers and basically handed off all the work to a helper class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to set the filename when you click on the Download link in Media field on an item in the media library?

[image: Media item with download link]

Let me know if I've misunderstood, and what you're after is somewhere else.

If this is the case, the URL of the download link is in the format `http://yoursite/sitecore/shell/download.aspx?file=A17A048DD4214081A5591B061E1E433A`

The relevant code is `<your_install>\sitecore\shell\download.aspx` and you'll want to decompile and have a look at `Sitecore.Shell.DownloadPage` in `Sitecore.Client.dll`.

Unfortunately it doesn't look like this is using any pipelines that you can hook into, so you will have to replace the download.aspx page with your own, that uses your own custom class behind the scenes.  If your class inherits from `Sitecore.Shell.DownloadPage`, you can overwrite the `WriteMediaItem` method to customise your file name.

The default (decompiled) version of this (SC8.1) looks like:

```
protected void WriteMediaItem(MediaItem mediaItem)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) mediaItem, "mediaItem");
  Stream mediaStream = mediaItem.GetMediaStream();
  string str = mediaItem.Extension;
  if (!str.StartsWith(".", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
    str = "." + str;
  this.WriteCacheHeaders(mediaItem.Name + str, mediaStream.Length);
  WebUtil.TransmitStream(mediaStream, this.Response, Settings.Media.StreamBufferSize);
}
```

Where you can see it uses the mediaItem.Name concatenated with the mediaItem.Extension to build the attachment filename (used in the private `WriteCacheHeaders` method).

You can replace this protected method with your own logic.  As this is a Sitecore file, you should take care when upgrading to ensure that your solution still works and that you track your changes (since the upgrade may overwrite or delete your Sitecore files).

Comment: Thanks Jason for the answer, but I am constructing the URLs using MediaManager.GetMediaUrl() which returns something like /-/media/files/filename.pdf to use within the website and it does not use download.aspx