# "ForceDownload" downloads images in CM even when set to false

Tags: content-editor, media-library

I'm using Sitecore 9.1.1 and SXA 1.8.1.

I needed to make .png and .txt files downloadable in my site, so I followed the answer [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/20217/3547), and added a config patch where `forceDownload` is set to true for said media types.

**The weird behavior:** Whenever I open any item in my content editor, (just clicking on it really), it would *instantly* download a .png file! whether it is an image I attached inside my item, or just the icon sometimes, it is always downloaded!

Stranger still, is that I tried setting the `forceDownload` attributes to "false" in my patch file, but the instant downloads continued.

I have also tried removing the config patch altogether, and checking from http://myinstance/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx that the actual loaded config is false, but still the instant downloads continue.

What could be the problem here? I'm running out of ideas as to what could be wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Even after an app_pool restart, you still experience the same issue?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I tried to do an "iisreset" if that's what you mean, and the issue still persists.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and/or try an incognito browser tab. p.s. there were links to solution to your actual problem in the answer you linked to

Comment: @jammykam I tried clearing my cache and incognito too, i saw the other solutions in the link but they didn't work for my case, i currently just need to fix the autodownload that happens

Comment: Try to check in multiple browser

Comment: I have the same issue here, and found that setting `Media.RequestProtection.Enabled` to `false` fixes it. Obviously that's not a proper solution, but maybe you can try and let me know if it's the same at your end.

Comment: @maz I added an answer of what worked for me, but the cause of the issue is still a mystery to me tbh..

Comment: @MieElMansy In my case, we had a custom MediaProvider which overrode the `GetMediaUrl` method. It turns out that in the default `MediaProvider`, Sitecore also calls this method when generating a thumbnail. We added a check that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So after multiple tries with "iisreset", clearing my cache, trying incognito mode and different browsers, the issue stopped happening as suddenly as it began. I guess the configuration was cached somewhere and was eventually removed.