# Download Sitecore Media file from UI

Tags: media-library, links

In our application we have an excel (xlsx/xls) file in medial library. We are trying to create a functionality to be able to download this excel using an html anchor or button.

But when we click on the achor/button, we get erro "The requested document was not found"

Currently I have following changes done but it’s not working. Please suggest right approach to do this.

1.Config Setting

```
  <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting patch:instead="setting[@name='Media.RequestExtension']" name="Media.RequestExtension" value=""/>
    </settings>
 </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

2. View(cshtml) code

```
< a href="http://xyx.com/-/media/TCW/Dotcom/TestFactSheet.xlsx" />
```

3. Controller code to get the media Url

```
var  factSheetItem = SitecoreContext.GetItem<Item>(usPage.MorningStarFactSheetLink.Id);
MediaUrlOptions mediaOptions= new MediaUrlOptions();
mediaOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
mediaOptions.AbsolutePath =true;
var mediaItemUrl =  MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(factSheetItem, mediaOptions);
vm.Fields.MorningStarFactSheetLink = mediaItemUrl;
```

4. We have tried file/General Link Field Types for Template field

Note: we are facing this issue for all types of files pdf/excel not just excel.

I get below error screen. 
[image]

Please do suggest correct approach to implement it.

Comment: Take a look at https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/how-to-force-download-media-based-on-business-logic     Alternativelty here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/134/change-default-file-name-when-downloading-from-media-library?rq=1

Comment: When you say it doesn't work. What do you mean? It doesn't output the right extension, the link doesn't work? Also, are you having issues with normal images such as jpg etc.? The view code seems to be also the rendered view, not what's in the view file, that could be useful.

Comment: When i say its not working, I mean when we click on link to download excel-sheet, it show error "The requested document was not found"

Comment: Can you check the output screen and see if you are able to see the desired link in the anchor tag.

Comment: Have you published the media library?